# Iterate through dataframe rows and replace elements of strings within a specific column

Tags: python

I have some tables from the Bureau of Labor Statistics that I converted to cvs files in Python. The 'Item' column has some rows with multiple '.' . I'm trying to iterate through these rows and replace these '.' with '' .

I've tried:

```
for row in age_df_1989['Item']:
   if '.' in row:
      age_df_1989['Item'].replace('.','')
```

Any ideas on what I can do for this?

Answer (score 2):

No assigning `age_df_1989['Item'].replace('.','')` to a variable won't change the original data, you need to do this:

```
for row in age_df_1989['Item']:
   if '.' in row:
      row['Item'] = row['Item'].replace('.','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `apply`

```
age_df_1989['Item'] = age_df_1989['Item'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('.', '')
```

Simple & faster than a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use the vectorised str method [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html): This is much faster than the iterrows or for loop or apply option.

You can do something as simple as

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].str.replace('old value','new value')
```

For your example, do this:

```
age_df_1989['Item'] = age_df_1989['Item'].str.replace('.', '')
```

Here's an example output of this:

```
c = ['Name','Item']
d = [['Bob','Good. Bad. Ugly.'],
     ['April','Today. Tomorrow'],
     ['Amy','Grape. Peach. Banana.'],
     ['Linda','Pink. Red. Yellow.']]
import pandas as pd
age_df_1989 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = c)
print (age_df_1989)
age_df_1989['Item'] = age_df_1989['Item'].str.replace('.', '')
print (age_df_1989)
```

Dataframe: age_df_1989 : Original

```
    Name                   Item
0    Bob       Good. Bad. Ugly.
1  April        Today. Tomorrow
2    Amy  Grape. Peach. Banana.
3  Linda     Pink. Red. Yellow.
```

Dataframe: age_df_1989 : After the replace command

```
    Name                Item
0    Bob       Good Bad Ugly
1  April      Today Tomorrow
2    Amy  Grape Peach Banana
3  Linda     Pink Red Yellow
```